# Craft CMS - 3.6.11.1 - Why are Assets Backed Up to Temporary Storage?

Tags: craft3, assets, digitalocean

Since updating Craft CMS to the latest version I noticed that our uploaded files get backed-up daily to temporary storage. Uploaded files live on DigitalOcean Spaces so we have no need to back up these files to the same server Craft CMS resides on.

- Files are stored on the following path: `storage/runtime/temp/tfxrsolmuf/images`
- This caused us to go over our allotted disk space and cause the server to go down
- The backup is happening daily
- Using Craft 3.6.10
- We use the DigitalOcean spaces volume plugin

[image]

[image]

Comment: What types of files exist inside of those 10 random character folder names? Images? The only place I can see in Craft that writes a random folder to the `storage/runtime/temp` folder is when restoring a database backup.

Comment: Hi @BradBell - that is correct inside each folder is our assets. Images and file uploads etc...

Comment: @DanLee as an aside, I'd recommend running some sort of [daily cron script](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-send-email-alert-when-your-disk-space-gets-low) which alerts you if disk is getting low... say 80% full so your server doesn't accidentally go down again.

Answer (score 1):

We have isolated the issue to a crone job connected with the Remote Backup Plugin for Craft.

Commenting out the following stops the daily backup.

```
# /home/forge/www.example.com/craft remote-backup/volume/create
# /home/forge/www.example.com/craft remote-backup/volume/prune
```

I think there is an issue with trying to connect to the remote storage location.